# For Join Attributes by Location, how should I set up geometric predicate in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I want to calculate the distribution of attributes of a vector layer in a grid layer by using "Join Attributes by Location (summary)". My question is, how to set the geometric predicate so that each polygon is counted in only one grid?

Screenshot of the distribution of vector and grid layers：

[image]

Comment: Convert your houses (?) to centroids.

Comment: But centroids will still have containment/contact etc. relationships with multiple grids?

Comment: Centroids are points. If you are able to demonstrate that a point can be contained by several not overlapping polygons, you shouldn't be posting here, you should be writing a paper and getting ready for you nobel prize.

Comment: You're right, thanks. But I don't think a little politeness will cost you anything.

Comment: I am sorry if the ironic remark was too much.

Comment: Apology accepted. Just a little surprised. To me it was just a 'no reaction' question, but apparently it should be compared to a major discovery and a Nobel Prize.

Comment: Oh you'd be surprised in how many n-dimensional realms that point *contains the polygon*...but in your Euclidean 2D plane, using centroids is the way to go. The key is true *containment*, to rule out the extremely unlikely case of a point sitting exactly on a boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I understand it, the centroids are either inside the grid or on the edge line (a small but theoretically possible probability). the geometric predicate description is a bit unclear.